# Access Windows Phone folder from Windows Store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to access Windows Phone StorageFolder that you get access by FolderPicker after app restart?

The problem is that Path property of StorageFolder is empty, so there is no way to get StorageFolder from Path, and I can't see any value that I could store to access (create) new StorageFolder object for the same folder.

Comment: Did you try FutureAccessList?

Comment: The problem is that I can't store any value to reference the folder on app restart. StorageFolder has no Path. It has RelativePathid, but I can't seem to do anything with that.

Comment: Take a look at FutureAccessList, as Jon suggested. FutureAccessList stores whole StorageItem for future use and associate it with a token that can be used even after app restart.

Comment: Well, FutureAccessListEntry has 2 properties - MetaData and Token, and they are both strings. Token is the text I chose when I create new entry, so it is useless as I can't get folder path (if I could I could store it other way anyway). How do I create StorageFolder from that? If you have some exact answer or code, please post below, and I'll mark it as answer, otherwise this doesn't seem like a solution.

Comment: OK, this seems to be the answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/eaa32f27-94bf-45f9-8407-30441f84af3f/futureaccesslist-is-a-queue-or-stack?forum=winappswithcsharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After useful suggestions  by Jon and Andrei, here is the code that I found to work:

```
await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(entry.Token);
```